# Application download logs on mac os 10.8.3

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

I want to know where can I find my applications downloads logs?
Like url that the application downloaded or downloading now

Answer (score 0):

This shows a list of URLs downloaded by applications that use quarantine events:

`sqlite3 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV* 'select LSQuarantineDataURLString from LSQuarantineEvent' | grep .`

Files also have metadata for download locations:

`find ~/Documents -name '*.pdf' -exec mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemWhereFroms {} \;`

This would show download locations only for files that have a quarantine attribute added by Safari:

`find ~/Documents -name '*.pdf' | while read -r f; do xattr -p com.apple.quarantine "$f" 2> /dev/null | grep -q com.apple.Safari && { echo "$f"; mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms "$f"; }; done`

If others were searching for a log of installed packages or software updates, see `/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist`.

Comment: I got this:
`kMDItemFSName     = "intel-ipartition-template-boot.dmg"`

`kMDItemWhereFroms = (null)`

when I ran this command:

`find ~/Desktop/ -name '*.dmg' -exec mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemWhereFroms {} \;`